# web API Frames - существует ли?

Tags: javascript, api, браузер

Добрый день! Возник вопрос - существует ли такое API и как до него достучаться через Javascript. Пояснения на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я кэп)) frames или window.frames

Comment: @Александр, мне кажется, это не оно) Просто схожие названия